# In which scenrion we can cover exception part in Schedule Class:

Tags: scheduled-apex, exception

I have written Schedule Class where I have added 2 batch classes that runs on Daily Basis.Below is the apex Class:

Apex Class:

```
 global class UserDeactivateBatchScheduler implements Schedulable {

        global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
            try{
            UserDeactivateBatch b = new UserDeactivateBatch();
            Database.executeBatch(b);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
            BatchUtil.trackErrorLogs('UserDeactivateBatch', 'Execute', 'Exception Line Number:' + ex.getLineNumber() + '~ Exception Type-' + ex.getTypeName()+  '~ Exception Message-' + ex.getmessage());
            }
            try{
            integer batchSize = 1;
            PendingEmailNotification batchDRAF=new 
  PendingEmailNotification();
            database.executebatch(batchDRAF,batchSize);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
            BatchUtil.trackErrorLogs('PendingEmailNotification', 'Execute', 'Exception Line Number:' + ex.getLineNumber() + '~ Exception Type-' + ex.getTypeName()+  '~ Exception Message-' + ex.getmessage());  
            }
        }

    }
```

Test Class:

```
@istest
public class UserDeactivateBatchSchedulerTest {

    public static testmethod void testbatch(){
        Test.startTest();
        // This test runs a scheduled job at midnight Sept. 3rd. 2022
        String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 3 9 ? 2022';

        // Schedule the test job
        String jobId = System.schedule('UserDeactivateBatchSchedulerTest', CRON_EXP, new UserDeactivateBatchScheduler());

        // Get the information from the CronTrigger API object 
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId]; 

        // Verify the job has not run 
        System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered); 

        // Verify the next time the job will run 
        System.assertEquals('2022-09-03 00:00:00', String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));   
        Test.stopTest();   
    }
}
```

Test Class Runs Successfully and covers only Try Part.

**If I want to cover Catch part, I want to know in which scenrio, the above schedule class moves into catch block?**

I have tried multiple scenarios like changing the date to past but failed to cover the code coverage for Catch Block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructors for `UserDeactivateBatch` and `PendingEmailNotification` will determine whether you currently have a route to create an exception and obtain coverage of these lines. However, since the constructors take no parameters, the only clear route would be if those constructors perform queries and you could "seed" your test environment with bad data that would cause those constructors to crash.

Unfortunately, that would suggest that the constructors contain fairly bad code, so let's hope that's not the case.

The other route would be to modify your code to utilize some dependency injection. One way to do this would be to create a constructor on your Scheduleable that accepts a class implementing an interface `UserDeactivateBuilder` that you'd store for use in the `execute`:

```
 global void UserDeactivateBatchScheduler(Object<UserDeactivateBuilder> builder)
```

The interface could define a `newUserDeactivateBatch()` and `newPendingEmailNotification()` method that would construct these instances for your class. Your test could then pass a test object implementing this interface, but which throws an exception in each of those methods instead of actually constructing and returning a new instance.

In real usage, you would implement a parameterless `UserDeactivateBatchScheduler()` constructor that would call the constructor `UserDeactivateBatchScheduler(Object<UserDeactivateBuilder> builder)` with an instance of a class `ProductionUserDeactivateBuilder` that constructs real instances in `newUserDeactivateBatch()` and `newPendingEmailNotification()`.

... but that seems like a lot of effort to cover two lines, and might be better spent improving code coverage elsewhere.

Comment: Thank You. I will probably focus on other test class code coverage part.Current Code Coverage is 66% which is sufficient :)